# Fully delete genymotion emulators

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I was trying to set up a genymotion emulator a specific way, yesterday.

In the process I made about 7 different emulators.

I have since deleted them all.

Before, I had 20+GB. Now I have 7GB.

My assumption is that although the device is deleted, the harddrive file isn't?

Though I have checked everywhere for them.

Is there a special way to fully delete an emulator?
(They are no longer listed in genymotion interface)

Answer (score 3):

Have you opened VirtualBox which Genymotion runs on, to see if the virtual machine is still existing there? You should be able to delete the emulator for good there.

Comment: Thanks but they are not, i have checked it. Good idea though.

Comment: Have you done a full disk search for .vbox files, or emptied you trash bin? :)

Answer (score 2):

try to clear cache on the misc tab.
On windows go to AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion folder  and remove the (old device) files in the deployed, ova and templates directories.
e.g for me they are in C:\Users\prashant.majhwar\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion folder.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I have also tried this. But the folder is empty. And i have cleared cache, 300MB